# Не удается редактировать state в React. Encountered two children with the same key, `(id элемента)`

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, key, setstate

Я делаю to do приложение, и мне надо, чтобы по кнопке "clear completed" обновлялся state в компоненте app.

**Задумка:**

Есть state в компоненте app, где хранится информация о задачах в виде списка. При каждом нажатии на чекбокс стейт обновляется по id элемента, и переменная isEnd определенного элемента обновляется на состояние его чекбокса. По нажатию кнопки "clear completed" происходит фильтрация стейта, где пачкой удаляются те элементы, которые соответствуют условию `isEnd == true`. Данная фильтрация присваивается новому элементу, а он, в свою очередь, передается в `this.setState({todos: newListTodos})`. Список элементов отображается при помощи функции `.map((~) => {~})`. Каждому элементу присвается `key={todo.id}` Такая вот задумка.

**Проблема:**

При первом удалении все происходит абсолютно корректно, но далее после нажатия на чекбокс задача дублируется, и в консоли пишется:
*Encountered two children with the same key, `(id элемента)`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.*
Помимо этого, переменная newListTodos корректно обновляется, а сам стейт остается прежним.

**Путь решения:**

И в интернете, и в документации React говорится о том, что при каждом изменении стейта нужно передавать новый объект не напрямую и иметь старый объект, чтобы реакту было с чем сравнивать новый объект. Но старый объект поимел меня. Я не знаю как реализовать метод корректного обновления стейта.

**App.js:**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      all: true,
      active: false,
      completed: false,
      todos: [{
          text: "Complete online JavaScript course",
          isEnd: true,
          id: 0,
        },
        {
          text: "Jog around the park 3x",
          isEnd: false,
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          text: "10 minutes meditation",
          isEnd: false,
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          text: "Read for 1 hour",
          isEnd: false,
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          text: "Pick up groceries",
          isEnd: false,
          id: 4,
        },
        {
          text: "Complete Todo App on Frontend Mentor",
          isEnd: false,
          id: 5,
        },
      ],
    };

    this.clearCompleted = this.clearCompleted.bind(this)
  }

  //вывод контента

  clearCompleted() {
    const newListTodos = this.state.todos.filter((element) => element.isEnd === false)
    this.setState({
      todos: newListTodos
    })
  }
}
```

**listToDo.js:**

```js
class listToDo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.todos.length > 0)
      return (
        <div className="list-todos">
          {this.props.todos.map((this_toDo) => (
            <ToDo key={this_toDo.id} updateCount={this.props.updateCount} todoInfo={this_toDo} />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    else
      return (
        <div>
          <h2 className="grey">List a void.</h2>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Может эта проблема и покажется банальной, но для меня, как для новичка в реакт, это вызывает трудности.

Comment: Если что-то вызывает трудности - значит нужно перейти "от сложного" к чему-то более "простому" и научиться делать простое. Потом переходить к более сложному. Начнем с того что Реакт продвигает функциональные компоненты с хуками, а у тебя классы... Оба, приведенных тобой, класса никак не связаны... `listToDo` - компоненты принято называть с большой буквы...

Comment: связаны, я обрезал некоторую часть кода, а listToDo приложил для демонстрации реализации вывода объектов, может быть я там накосячил

Comment: При рендере, у вас дубликаты номеров `key={this_toDo.id}` вот реакт и ругается. Посмотрите, как и где вы добавляете элементы и какие id при этом получаете.

Comment: но каким образом создаются эти дубликаты id, если старые элементы по нажатию кнопки удаляются, а другие остаются без изменений? по идее изменятся же только размер нового списка, а старый, кстати, не принимает значение нового списка при первом рендере. Как избежать таких дубликатов?